# TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, discord.py, send

This has been happening for a while. I used discord.py. This is an example:

```
test = input("Write something:")
await message.channel.send("You wrote:", test)
```

What it writes in the console:

```
>>TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According discord.py [send() documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) you should pass a message string as a positional argument. I believe you want to write something like this:

```py
test = input("Write something:")
await message.channel.send(f"You wrote: {test}")
```